# Probabilities of Bivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have the following normal distribution that all of the parameter are known
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        X_1\\
       X_2\\
            \end{pmatrix}
\sim   N\left[\begin{pmatrix}
        \mu_1 \\
         \mu_2 \\
             \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^2 & \rho \\
         \rho & \sigma^2\\\end{pmatrix}
\right]$$

$1.$  $\Bbb P(X_1\le\mu_2) = \phi(\frac{\mu_2 - \mu_1}{\sigma})$
is that correct?

$2.$  How do I calculate $\Bbb P(X_1< X_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct!
2. It is easy to verify that the marginal distributions are

$X_1\sim N(\mu_1;\sigma^2)$

$X_2\sim N(\mu_2;\sigma^2)$

with $Cov(X_1;X_2)=\rho$

Then it is immediate to calculate

$\mathbb{P}[X_1<X_2]=\mathbb{P}[X_1-X_2<0]$

via distribution of $Z=X_1-X_2$ that is known

Comment: so $X_1 - X_2 \sim N(\mu_1 - \mu_2 ;\rho \sigma^2)$ ?

Comment: Why is the variance $\rho \sigma^2$ and not $\rho $?

Comment: @MC 1325 : sorry, it was a typo...I amend my answer but the procedure is the same

Comment: thank you!. is the variance of $X_1 + X_2$ is also $\rho$?

Comment: @MC1325 :  the variance of $X_1\pm X_2=2(\sigma^2\pm\rho)$